# Yi windows intallation failure. ExitFailure 3

Tags: windows, haskell, cabal, yi-editor

I tried to install it on windows 7, 32 bit. And got an error at the end:

```
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
Failed to install yi-0.7.1
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
yi-0.7.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 3
```

How can I install it? Maybe there is some specific dependencies, that builds on windows? For example, I could only build gtk-0.12.4 on 0.12.4 dependencies version's.
(this offtopic problem problem described here: [Gtk2hs windows 7 installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251902/gtk2hs-windows-7-installation)
)

The full log is here: http://pastebin.com/RdVMx9kP

---

****UPD****

With cabal 1.16.0.

`cabal install yi -f-vty -fpango -v3`
gives: http://pastebin.com/fwFg6z4D

With cabal 1.18.0.2

`cabal install yi -f-vty -fpango -v3`
gives: http://pastebin.com/qnmp2Jtd

`cabal install yi-0.7.0 -f-vty -fpango -v3`
gives: http://pastebin.com/tZ93aaXY

****UPD2****

`cabal install yi -f-vty -f-pango -v3`
gives: http://pastebin.com/7tR9iVSf

It installed yi... but can it work without pango?

Comment: What version of cabal and ghc do you have?

Comment: ghc 7.6.3, cabal 1.16.0. @David

Comment: You might try upgrading cabal and see if that helps (the current stable version of cabal-install is 1.18.0.2). Also, running with cabal with -v2 or -v3 might give you more detailed error messages.

Comment: Please see ****UPD**** section in question, @David

Comment: Well, first of all, Vty does not have Windows support. Secondly, I recommend you try to install from Yi GitHub repository. If you have further problems, please come to #yi on Freenode and we can probably help you out.

Comment: I'll try github. But about vty: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Yi#Windows Are you kidding me?!! @Mateusz

Comment: Nope, not kidding. Actually reading your question again I don't know why I said that, you already disable it yourself: `-f-vty` disables it while `-fvty` would enable it. The wiki page you linked, Yi README and Vty README all state that there's no Vty for Windows. FYI I don't expect the git version to get rid of your problem but it's something to try and it certainly makes it easier helping you further

Comment: Please also see ****UPD2****, @Mateusz

Comment: We only offer Pango and Vty as the frontends at the moment so I think what you got is basically a headless install (didn't know you could!). This does indicate a problem with your GTK rather than with Yi however. Can you try installing other applications dependent on GTK and see how that goes? For example, I have a very small package on Hackage called `himg`, perhaps try that.

Answer (score 2):

Try

`cabal install yi -f-vty -f-pango`

to see if the issue is with pango or not.

Comment: **I'll do it**, but I successfuly installed and used gtk-0.12.4... so pango-0.12.4 is also installed.

Comment: I did it. Please see ****UPD2**** section in question, @Guest.